# CupertinoDatePicker to SQLite in Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I want to make an alarm app using CupertinoDatePicker, and I have no idea how to save the time to SQLite. For label(textfield) of alarm, I can just add the  `onChanged: (String label){this.label = label;},`, but in the DatePicker plugin, there's something already in the (). It's my first time to use SQLite, so I'll appreciate it if anyone can tell solutions.

```
                               Container( height: 280,
                                  child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                                      mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.time,

                                      initialDateTime:DateTime.now(),
                                      onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) {
                                       TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(newDateTime);
                                        },
                                     use24hFormat: false,
                                      minuteInterval: 1,
                                    ),
                              ), 

                                Container( width: 350,
                                child: TextField(
                                  onChanged: (String label){ this.label = label;},
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500), 
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(     
                                  hintText: 'alarm label',  
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(      
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),   
                                          ),  
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                                       ),  
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I've learned that I need to transfer changed time to String.

```
    onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) {
      this.time = TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(newDateTime).toString();
      },
```